# AMQP RabbitMQ Consumers being killed and aren't restarted

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm trying to fix a tricky issue here in a Springboot RabbitMQ AMQP scenario.

1. I've got multiple queues with concurrency set to 2:
2. The application starts and consumes messages normally. I've got 3 instances of this application running so I've usually have 6 consumers running consuming messages.
3. After a while (could be days) I can see in the logs that an exception such as `Shutdown Signal: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - delivery acknowledgement on channel 1 timed out. Timeout value used: 1800000 ms. This timeout value can be configured, see consumers doc guide to learn more, class-id=0, method-id=0)` is thrown.
4. This closes the consumer thread, AMQP doesn't recreate it and this consumer is gone. This happens until I've got no more  consumers left and then the queues keep receiving messages but there's no consumer available to consume them.

Relevant information:

1. This is a long processing scenario, meaning that I'm using RabbitMQ to orchestrate a ETL workload and because of that some of the messages take a long time. I've seen in other answers here that this could happen because it took too long to process the message and then it timed-out, so I've changed the consumer to perform a manual ACK:

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
@RabbitListener(
        bindings = @QueueBinding(
                value = @Queue(value = "${rabbitmq.queue.name}", durable = "true"),
                exchange = @Exchange(value = "${rabbitmq.exchange.name}"),
                key = "${rabbitmq.queue.name}"
        ),
        concurrency = "${rabbitmq.queue.concurrency}",
        ackMode = "MANUAL")
public class ExampleConsumer {

    @RabbitHandler
    @CircuitBreaker(name = "CONSUMER_CB", fallbackMethod = "fallback")
    @SneakyThrows
    public void extract(SomeMessage message,
                        Channel channel,
                        @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long tag) {
        channel.basicAck(tag, Boolean.FALSE);
        handleMessage(message);
    }

}
```

You can consider that `handleMessage(message)` method takes a long time to process.

2. I've seen an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57935785/2113605) by Garry Russel that says that "The most common cause, by far, for problems like this is the container thread is "stuck" somewhere in user code - either in the listener, or code called by the listener; e.g. a deadlock.

First step is to take a thread dump the next time it happens to see what the listener container thread(s) are doing."

However since this only happens in production code and it's difficult to know when it will happen, I can't get a thread dump easily.

Also, considering that I'm doing a manual ACK, am I wrong to assume that this error should never happen? Because by the looks of it this should only happen if the consumer took too long to process the message and didn't ACKed it, which is not the case here.

So, these are my questions:

- why doesn't a manual ACK solves this issue?
- what can I do to have AMQP to recreate the consumers automatically?
- if I can't do that automatically, how can I create an watchdog of sorts that can check the status of queues and recreate consumers in case the queue doesn't have any?
- is there anyway that I can understand what error is causing this? Maybe a listener that I can implement to grab details of the inner exception?

Comment: I was facing the similar type of issue in my project where consumers are automatically getting removed after some time. Most probably this issue occurs only when you use threading to create multiple consumers. To resolved this issue, I have created one light weight API which can check consumers counts my invoking RabbitMQ API. And if there are less or no consumer then it's creates new consumer.  To invoke this API, I have configured on cron-job which runs after every 2 minutes.

Comment: @GaurangDelvadiya do you have a sample on how did u do that? that would work as a watchdog for this scenario

Comment: Sure, I will share it with you by today EOD (Asis/Kolkata).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach here,

**List item:**

Create one API with the following steps,

**Step 1:** Create Get endpoint

**Step 2:** Define all the queues with their required consumers count in Enum or Env

**Step 3:** Invoke RabbitMQ api `curl -i -u guest:guest http://localhost:15672/api/queues` to fetch all the queue details

**Step 4:** Loop through every queue and check if for the consumer counts

**Step 5:** If consumer counts are less then create missing number of consumer threads

**Step 6:** Return response

While checking consumer counts please make sure that you are also checking the Virtual Host as well. Because same queue with different Virtual Hosts is also possible. Ignore if you only have single Virtual Host.

**Setup CronJob:**

Create one cronjob in GCP or AWS or anywhere you want and invoke this API on the interval of two minutes. If you are not familiar with cronjob then you can check it online.